# load /execute module based bootstraps from each module in certain order

Tags: zend-framework

I have module boostrap files in each module and these are being load (I believe) in file system order. How can make them load/execute in certain order which I specify?

I have 4 modules in my application.

```
1. 1module
2. 2module
3. 3module
4. 4module.
```

every module has its own bootstrap which loads according to the order of file system. 
in above case. application loads bootstraps of above modules in following order.

```
1. loads bootstrap of module 1
2. loads bootstrap of module 2
3. loads bootstrap of module 3
4. loads bootstrap of module 4.
```

but I like to load the bootstraps of modules in following order or in any order which specify.

```
1. loads bootstrap of module 3
2. loads bootstrap of module 1
3. loads bootstrap of module 4
4. loads bootstrap of module 2
```

How can I change the sequence?

relevent reading but not what I am looking for.

http://phpdev.ro/zf-tutorial-series-part-1-module-based-app.html

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=1589

http://www.stephenrhoades.com/?p=386

Comment: whats wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, one does not explicitly specify bootstrap order.

However, if one application resource or `_initXXX()` method needs another resource to be initialized first, you would call:

```
$bootstrap->bootstrap('someResource');
$someResource = $bootstrap->getResource('someResource');
```

to ensure that the resource named `someResource` is all bootstrapped up before using it.

Note that if you are in an application bootstrap extending `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap`, then the calls are:

```
$this->bootstrap('someResource');
$someResource = $this->getResource('someResource');
```

If you are in a module bootstrap extending `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`, then it changes slightly to:

```
$application = $this->getApplication();
$application->bootstrap('someResource');
$someResource = $application->getResource('someResource');
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. I have update my question with example.

Comment: Why do you need them to run in a particular order? If this issue is not dependency as I suggested, then perhaps these processes are not appropriate to bootstrap, but should instead be `routeStartup()` front-controller plugins (whose order you can specify by setting a stack-index when you register them).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to prefix the modules with a letter in alphabetical order. Alternatively, override Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap/Zend_Application_Resource_Modules and give it a config file with the order it should bootstrap in.