# How to execute module bootstrap resources present inside another module's bootstrap in Zend Framework 1?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, bootstrapping

I am bootstrapping my application with `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap` inside the various module directories.  How can I require that a resource inside another module's bootstrap be executed first?

```
// app/modules/user/Bootstrap.php
class User_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initUser()
    {
    }
}

// app/modules/author/Bootstrap.php
class Author_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAuthor()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('user'); // Fatal:  Resource matching 'user' not found
    }
}
```

Comment: You do understand that everything in all of your bootstrap files gets all mashed together and executed with every request? It is wise with ZF1 to only put resources in the bootstrap that need to be executed _**every**_ request. A lot of the things we put into the bootstrap may be better off as plugins or helpers of one stripe or another. Sorry didn't scroll down enough :)

Comment: @RockyFord Yeah, I think I'll stick with plugins and listen for routeStartup.  I would like to identify the user properly as soon as possible, because then I would add stylesheets/scripts based on their role.  Do you feel any conditional logic (besides detecting environment) in the bootstrap is a bad idea?

Comment: If you need stuff in the bootstrap, then you need it. Just be aware of the potential costs. For loading resources based on user role, you might be able to incorporate that particular logic into your ACL plugin (depending on how you're doing ACL). If you want to load user resources you may need to wait for `routeShutdown` or `preDispatch` so that the user has been determined, don't worry nothing will display until after the entire dispatch loop is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use plugins to achieve this fine-grained functionality, as execution order cannot be managed properly, therefore making module bootstraps a poor choice to place code with dependencies.

Used referenced answer below to base my decision:

[load /execute module based bootstraps from each module in certain order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11133234/712558)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Where-are-the-module-bootstraps-objets-saved-td3070011.html) from the ZF1 mailing list, you can access the module-bootstraps via the modules resource of the application bootstrap.

Man, what a mouthful. Here's what I mean:

```
// app/modules/user/Bootstrap.php
class User_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initUser()
    {
    }
}

// app/modules/author/Bootstrap.php
class Author_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAuthor()
    {
        $app = $this->getApplication(); // it's actually the application *bootstrap*
        $app->bootstrap('modules');
        $modulesResource = $app->getResource('modules'); 
        $userBootstrap = $modulesResource->user;
        $userBootstrap->bootstrap('user'); // should be cool
    }
}
```

In my own experience, as soon as one of my module-level resources needs to be referenced in more than one module - especially during bootstrapping - I just push the bootstrapping of that resource up into the application-level bootstrap.

Comment: I feel like this is so close.  I'm getting a 'circular resource dependency' error with `$app->bootstrap('modules')`, because it is in the process of starting and has not completely run (and I guess I'm trying to start it up again).  If I comment that out, I am unable to get the modules resource (returns null).  If my script is in the process of bootstrapping my modules, how can I get its resource?

Comment: Do you have an `_initModules()` method in any of your bootstraps __in addition to__ a `frontController.resources.modules[] = ` declaration in `application/configs/application.ini`? That could account for your circular dependency error.

Comment: I have `resources.modules = []`, and no _initModules method in any of my bootstraps.  I don't think this would bear any weight on my question, but I am subclassing `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap` and having my module bootstraps extend from that subclass. Stepping through the program, I see `'modules' => true` in the application bootstrap's `$_started` array right before the exception is thrown.

Comment: Sorry for my typo above in which I suggest the incorrect syntax `frontController.resources.modules[] =`. One last thing: Try `resources.modules[] =` instead of `resources.modules = []`. Failing that, maybe we cheap put and just push any common resources up to the application-level bootstrap? Then, we never have to manually bootstrap the 'modules' resource; it's handled by the entry in `application.ini`.

Comment: I'm using an array for my config, and I've tried setting resources['modules'] to an array and empty string, but no such luck (same circular dependency issue).  I suppose I may push up common resources to the application level, but my bootstrap is getting fat and unwieldy enough as it is.  Thanks for your help.